# How to use \csname ... \endcsname with \ref?

Tags: macros, cross-referencing

I have to get value of a dynamical macro where the index is given by `\ref{mymarker}`. Is it possible to do? I define a set of macros with a predefined counter 'mycounter' as

```
\expandafter\newcommand\csname mymacro\the\value{mycounter} \endcsname{mytext}
```

where 'mytext' depends on the value of counter.

After that I define a new command

```
\newcommand{\anotherref}[1]{\csname mymacro\ref{#1} \endcsname}
```

the code like

```
\anotherref{mymarker}
```

does not work. The idea is that this command should give not the counter value related to 'mymarker', like `\ref{mymarker}` gives, but rather the text 'mytext', which is also related to 'mymarker'.

Comment: Look at the package `refcount` and `\getrefnumber`

Comment: What should happen if the reference `mymarker` is undefined? How should `\anotherref` behave, if the macro to be used is not defined? Also you have a space at the end of the macro name (on purpose or accidentally).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers and comments! Everything works with the package refcount.

Comment: Since people have found the question interesting they will want to know the answer. Why not post yours, as a complete MWE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following example shows an implementation using package `refcount`.

- `\mymacrodef` defines `\mymacro<num>` using the current counter value of `mycounter` for `<num>`. The definition starts with `\newcommand{\mymacro<num>}`.
- `\mymacroget{<num>}` calls `\mymacro<num>`.
- `\mymacroundefined` is used if `\mymacroget` could not find `\mymacro<num>`.
- `\mymacroref{<label>}` extracts the number from the specified label and calls `\mymacroget` with the number. If the reference `<label>` is undefined, `\mymacroundefined` is used. The label name may contain babel shorthand characters.
- `\mymacrorefexp{<label>}` behaves like `\mymacroref` with the following differences:

  - The macro can be used in expandable context, because it is expandable in exact two expansion steps, see example below.
  - Babel shorthand characters are not supported, because this requires an assignment that breaks expandability.
  - If the reference is undefined, then the user is not given a warning, because that breaks expandability. If possible, use `\refused{<label>}` outside the expandable context to get the warning in case of an undefined reference.

The example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}[2010/12/01]
\usepackage{ltxcmds}

\newcounter{mycounter}

\makeatletter

% \mymacrodef defines a macro \mymacro<number> that gets
% the number from the current counter setting for `myounter`.
\newcommand*{\mymacrodef}{%
  \expandafter\newcommand
  \csname mymacro\the\value{mycounter}\endcsname
}

% \mymacroget{<number>} calls \mymacro<number>
% if the macro exists and \mymacroundefined otherwise.
% It is expandable in two expansion steps.
\newcommand*{\mymacroget}[1]{%
  \romannumeral-`\x
  \ltx@ifundefined{mymacro\number#1}{%
    \ltx@space
    \mymacroundefined
  }{%
    \expandafter\ltx@space
    \csname mymacro\number#1\endcsname
  }%
}   

\newcommand*{\mymacroundefined}{\textbf{??}}

% \mymacroref{<label>} is not expandable and gets the number
% from the reference <label>
\newcommand*{\mymacroref}[1]{%
  \refused{#1}%
  \IfRefUndefinedBabel{#1}{%
    \mymacroundefined
  }{%
    % with babel shorthand support
    \begingroup
      \csname @safe@actives@true\endcsname
    \expandafter\endgroup
    \expandafter\mymacroget\expandafter{%
      \number\getrefnumber{#1}%
    }%
  }%
}

\newcommand*{\mymacrorefexp}[1]{%
  \romannumeral-`\x
  \IfRefUndefinedExpandable{#1}{%
    \ltx@space
    \mymacroundefined
  }{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ltx@space
    \mymacroget{\getrefnumber{#1}}%
  }%
}   
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mymacrodef{Text zero.}
\refstepcounter{mycounter}
\mymacrodef{Text one.}
\label{mylabel}
\refstepcounter{mycounter}
\mymacrodef{Text one again.}

\begin{itemize}
\item[0:] \mymacroget{0}
\item[1:] \mymacroget{1}
\item[42:] \mymacroget{42}
\item[mylabel:] \mymacroref{mylabel}
\item[undef:] \mymacroref{undef}

% Expandable stuff. Define macro \my that has the meaning
% of the macro \mymacro<number>, where <number> is stored
% in label `mylabel':

\refused{mylabel}
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\let
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\my 
\mymacrorefexp{mylabel}

\item[\texttt{\string\my}:] \texttt{\meaning\my}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Test output]

Answer (score 1):

Here is my toy example. I hope this can be useful for somebody. The problem is to define the command `\editor` and to use it for forming the title page. Each editor has his own original number and represents a certain country. In the main text names of editors, their numbers and the corresponding countries are also mentioned. The suggestion to use the package `refcount` allows me to resolve this problem in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}

\makeatletter

% Definition of the command \editor{name}{country}
\newcounter{editor@index}
\newcommand\editor[2]{\refstepcounter{editor@index}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname
 @editor@name\the\value{editor@index} \endcsname{#1}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname
 @editor@country\the\value{editor@index} \endcsname{#2}%
}

% Definition of the commands \nameref{marker} and \countryref{marker}
\newcommand{\nameref}[1]{\csname
@editor@name\getrefnumber{#1} \endcsname}
\newcommand{\countryref}[1]{\csname
@editor@country\getrefnumber{#1} \endcsname}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

% With the command \editor one can define the list of editors.
% It can also be used in the redefinition of \maketitle with 
% accessing to the name with 
% \csname @editor@name\the\value{editor@index} \endcsname and to the
% country with \csname @editor@country\getrefnumber{#1} \endcsname.
% One can also mark the editors with \label.

\editor{John Smith}{UK}\label{JS}
\editor{John Doe}{USA}\label{JD}

% Now one can change the order of \editor and always have the correct 
% referencing.

\nameref{JS} from~\countryref{JS} is referred as editor~\ref{JS}.
\nameref{JD} from~\countryref{JD} is referred as editor~\ref{JD}. 

\end{document}
```

Thank you very much again for the comments and suggestions!