# How to choose from a list for using result in \ref?

Tags: cross-referencing, xstring

Recently, in [choose from a list with xstring](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78354/choose-from-a-list-with-xstring), Geoff was asking about defining the command `\variation` that does the following:

```
\variation{1}{aaa;bbb;ccc} ----> aaa
\variation{2}{aaa;bbb;ccc} ----> bbb
\variation{3}{aaa;bbb;ccc} ----> ccc
```

There are a number of nice answers on this question. However, I have found that all of them have the same disadvantage: when I am trying to use the result of `\variation` in `\ref` or `\getrefnumber` from the package refcount, I get an error message.

To be more specific, consider the not-working example based on Heiko Oberdiek solution,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

 \newcommand*{\variation}[2]{%
  \edef\variationNext{%
    \noexpand\StrBetween[%
      \the\numexpr(#1)\relax,%
      \the\numexpr(#1)+1\relax
    ]%
  }%
  \variationNext{;#2;}{;}{;}\relax
}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
2+2=4 \label{aaa}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 3+3=6 \label{bbb}
\end{equation}

I can refer to these equations as equation~\ref{aaa} and
equation~\ref{bbb}.

Now I have the string ``aaa;bbb''. If I refer to these equations as
equation~\ref{\variation{1}{aaa;bbb}} and
equation~\ref{\variation{2}{aaa;bbb}}, I get an error message.

\end{document}
```

I have the same error message with all other proposed solutions. Is it possible to redefine the command `\variation` in such a way to it works correctly with `\ref` and with `\getrefnumber`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package `xstring`'s `\StrBetween` knows a final optional argument, that expects a command token to store the result. Thus `\variation` can be given an optional argument (at the beginning to avoid dropping spaces at the end). With optional argument the result is stored in the macro given there instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand*{\variation}[3][]{%
  \edef\variationNext{%
    \noexpand\StrBetween[%
      \the\numexpr(#2)\relax,%
      \the\numexpr(#2)+1\relax
    ]%
  }%
  \variationNext{;#3;}{;}{;}[#1]\relax
}
\newcommand*{\variationref}[2]{%
  \variation[\tmp]{#1}{#2}\ref{\tmp}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} 
2+2=4 \label{aaa}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}  
 3+3=6 \label{bbb}
\end{equation}

I can refer to these equations as equation~\ref{aaa} and
equation~\ref{bbb}.

Now I have the string ``aaa;bbb''. If I refer to these equations as
equation~\variation[\tmp]{1}{aaa;bbb}\ref{\tmp} and
equation~\variationref{2}{aaa;bbb}.                

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you. It seems that it works correctly also with replacing \ref by \getrefnumber.

Comment: Your solution is really nice but unfortunately it does not work for my final task even with \getrefnumber. I have formulated this task in my new question in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78653/how-to-test-if-a-given-refernce-belongs-to-a-list-of-labels. I would be very appreciate if you look it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with `\ref` is that it needs its argument to be a string, not the set of instructions to produce that string.

The best is to use a different command for such references, for instance

```
\varref{1}{aaa;bbb}
```

An almost straightforward modification of my answer does what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\variation}{ s O{;} m m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \geoff_variation_check:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
   {
    \geoff_variation_nocheck:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
   \tl_use:N \l__geoff_item_tl
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\varref}{s O{;} m m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \geoff_variation_check:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
   {
    \geoff_variation_nocheck:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
   \exp_args:NV \ref \l__geoff_item_tl
 }

\msg_new:nnn { variation }
 { index~out~of~bounds }
 { You~have~requested~an~item~that~doesn't~exist }
\seq_new:N \l__geoff_item_list_seq
\tl_new:N \l__geoff_item_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \geoff_variation_nocheck:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__geoff_item_list_seq { #1 } { #3 }
  \tl_set:Nx \l__geoff_item_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l__geoff_item_list_seq { #2 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \geoff_variation_check:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__geoff_item_list_seq { #1 } { #3 }
  \int_compare:nTF { #2 > \seq_count:N \l__geoff_item_list_seq }
   {
    \msg_warning:nn { variation }{ index~out~of~bounds }
    \tl_set:Nn \l__geoff_item_tl { --inexistentitem-- }
   }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l__geoff_item_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l__geoff_item_list_seq { #2 } }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\variation{3}{aaa;bbb;ccc;ddd;eee}

\variation[,]{3}{aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee}

\variation{1}{aaa}

\variation{2}{aaa}

\variation*{2}{aaa}

\begin{equation}
2+2=4 \label{aaa}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 3+3=6 \label{bbb}
\end{equation}

I can refer to these equations as equation~\ref{aaa} and
equation~\ref{bbb}.

If I refer to these equations as equation~\varref{1}{aaa;bbb} and
equation~\varref{2}{aaa;bbb}, I get correct numbers.

\end{document}
```

I left the original `\variation` command, though it appears not to be really needed.

The difference is that now `\geoff_variation_nocheck:nnn` stores the result in a token list variable and `\varref` calls it (or the `check` variant) and then does

```
\exp_args:NV \ref \l__geoff_item_tl
```

The behavior of `\varref` and `\varref*` are the same if there is no overflow; with `\varref*{3}{aaa;bbb}` you'd get a warning and `\ref{--inexistentitem--}` would be produced; with `\varref{3}{aaa;bbb}` you'd simply get `\ref{}`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. For me it is also important to `\varref` would work as suggested by you in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73349/how-to-use-csname-endcsname-with-ref command `\getrefnumber`. I will check it tomorrow.

Comment: @Andrew No, it wouldn't work. It can be done quite easily if you accept a syntax such as `\vargetrefnumber{2}{{aaa}{bbb}}`, otherwise a substantial change is needed. But it mostly depends on your real needs.

Comment: I was trying to play a bit with your code. There is a strange problem but most probably it is only related to my system. Yesterday evening I was compiling your code with a Windows PC (MiKTeX) and everything was working. Today I am doing the same with Linux and I am getting the error message about undefined control sequence \variation... I will try to fix the problem later. At the moment I have found that the solution of Heiko Oberdiek works even with \getrefnumber.