# Expansion rule for a character redefined with `\newunicodechar`

Tags: macros, tex-core, unicode, expansion

Consider the following code. With `xelatex` or `lualatex`, it produces three identical results. However, with `pdflatex` one shall get an error.

The main "macro" is a Unicode character `ᵢ`, defined to be a command with `\newunicodechar`. As comparison, two other macros with similar definitions are given:

- The first is a macro `\TestA` which is then used directly, one `\expandafter` is needed for `\@ifnextchar` to work properly.
- The second is another macro `\TestB` which is later called through `\csname...\endcsname`, and according to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78795/194994), three `\expandafter` is needed here.

With an Unicode engine, the character version seems to behave like `\TestA`. However, with `pdflatex`, neither one nor three `\expandafter` work.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@unisub\@unisubfalse
\newcommand{\@unisubA}{\if@unisub\else\sb\bgroup\fi}
\newcommand{\@unisubB}{\@ifnextchar\@unisubA{\@unisubtrue}{\egroup\@unisubfalse}}

\newunicodechar{ᵢ}{\@unisubA i \expandafter\@unisubB}
\def\testA{\@unisubA i \expandafter\@unisubB}
\def\testB{\@unisubA i \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@unisubB}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

$ᵢᵢᵢ$

$\testA \testA \testA$

$\csname testB\endcsname \csname testB\endcsname \csname testB\endcsname$

\end{document}
```

What is the expansion rule for a character defined with `\newunicodechar`?

Comment: I happen to have an implementation that interprets superscripts and subscripts in pdflatex and supports sequence of super/subscript characters correctly [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/618428/250119) (code written long ago, in retrospect I should not have used `prop` because it's kind of slow)

Comment: Side note × 2, the package only guarantee that when executed the Unicode character will do the task, I think it's bad idea to rely on what happens when these characters are executed. (nevertheless I think some internal code in expl3 assumes inputenc utf8 is "csname-safe", something like that?)

Answer (score 2):

With a unicode engine, the command `\newunicodechar{<char>}{<replacement>}` essentially does

```
\catcode`<char>=\active
\protected\def<char>{<replacement>}
```

but in an indirect way that allows `<char>` to be used in `<replacement>` with its original category code.

Thus `<char>` becomes a `\protected` macro.

For `pdflatex` the thing is different. If *n* is the hexadecimal slot of `<char>`, then the above is essentially the same as

`\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{`*n*`}{<replacement>}`

and `\@ifnextchar<char>` will fail miserably, because `<char>` has to be a multibyte character as will any `\expandafter` trick. Well, maybe some cleverly applied `\expandafter` trickery *might* work.

You can examine the `<char>` and decide whether it's a standard ASCII one or it starts with a multibyte prefix. In the latter case you can grab as many tokens as specified, do expansion and hope for the best.